guacamole-client change keyboard or mouse
I want to be able to make edits to the guacamole-client. For example, to change the size of the keyboard or mouse, it can replace the colors. Can you tell me how I can do this?
Point me in the right direction, please
I was able to run the guacamole-client only using docker, but I would like to be able to check my changes locally and understand which file I can make the changes I need.

A side note: the [apache] tag is unrelated here
